# How to fix UnboundLocalError: local variable 'o1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pytorch

I was making a binary classifier and faced this problem.

Code:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
```

```
class BinCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n, i, j, i1, j1, d, fc1, fc2):
        super().__init__()
        """
        n - source frame number of channels
        i - 1-st kernel_size height
        j - 1-st kernel_size width
        i1 - 2-nd kernel_size height
        j1 - 2-nd kernel_size width
        d - dropout rate
        fc1 - 1-st Linear layer size
        fc2 - 2-nd Linear layer size
        """
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(n, o1, kernel_size=[i, j])
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(o1, o2, kernel_size=[i1, j1])
        o1 = self._get_conv1_out(n)
        o2 = self._get_conv2_out(o1)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(d)
        self.fcl1 = nn.Linear(fc1, fc2)
        self.fcl2 = nn.Linear(fc2, 2)

    def _get_conv1_out(self, shape):
        o = self.conv1(torch.zeros(1, *shape))
        return int(np.prod(o.size()))

    def _get_conv2_out(self, shape):
        o = self.conv2(torch.zeros(1, *shape))
        return int(np.prod(o.size()))
```

And when i write

```
sd = BinCNN(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0.3, 300, 150)

print(sd)
```

This gives me the given error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/Документы/work/science/train/train.py", line 46, in <module>
    sd = BinCNN(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0.3, 300, 150)
  File "/home/name/Документы/work/science/train/train.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(n, o1, kernel_size=[i, j])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'o1' referenced before assignment
```

i tried to fix it by adding `model` before `self.conv1` but it didn't help

I googled about this but found nothing. Help me please

(I erased `def forward (self, x)` because stackoverflow swears at 'a lot of code)

Comment: Can you show your `forward` implementation **and** its call. It does matter here.

Comment: Sure ```def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fcl1(x))
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.fcl2(x)
        return x ```

Comment: The topic of your question and the body contradict, those are two different errors. For a start, extract a [mcve] and do a bit of research on the error message. Both of them are not new and there are lots of explanations for them online!

Comment: Sorry, at first the body and head of the question were the same, but then I was asked (look at the first answer) to change the error message, but I forgot to change the title

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you are trying to achieve with `o1` and `o2`. Can you tell us what `_get_conv1_out` and `_get_conv2_out` is supposed to return?

Comment: `o1` and `o2` mean the number of layers after `Conv2d`, and `_get_conv_out` in theory should count their number

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `_get_conv1_out` and `_get_conv2_out` before defining `conv1` and `conv2` respectively. They haven't been defined yet:

```
    o1 = self._get_conv1_out(n)
    o2 = self._get_conv2_out(o1)
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(n, o1, kernel_size=[i, j])
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(o1, o2, kernel_size=[i1, j1])
```

Comment: i tried to define `o1` and `o2` after, but that also gave an error

Comment: Please edit your question with the modification and updated error backtrace